# Casting to dynamic class crashes in method call

Tags: java, class, serialization

I have this code do load any serialized data:

```
public static <T> T loadData(String filename) {
        T o = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
            o = (T) oi.readObject();
            oi.close();
            fi.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return o;
    }
```

I call it with this:

```
ArrayList<String> data = loadData("a.dat");
```

But in this file I have another serialized object (e.g. a `java.util.File` object).
I expected a error at `o = (T) oi.readObject();`, which would be catched, but it crashes in the method call.
Why?

---

**EDIT:** Okay problem solved with the following code:

```
public static <T> T loadData(Class<T> expectedClass, String filename) {
        T o = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
            o = expectedClass.cast(oi.readObject());
            oi.close();
            fi.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return o;
    }
```

Comment: Whats the exception (message)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is a generic type, and is "erased" at runtime.  So at runtime, `T` is really just `Object`, and valid.

Only once you call it and try to coerce it to `ArrayList<String>` is the actual cast attempted, and fails.

Because of this, your IDE should be showing you an "unchecked" or "unsafe" warning on the cast to a generic type.  (This line: `o = (T) oi.readObject();`)

See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Thanks i got it finally working with the following code --> see edited question.

Comment: sure, there you go :)